# Ruby programming - avoid code duplication when named scopes are used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have multiple named scopes in my model. They have different names but same parameters.
Now, when I use these named scopes based on a condition I have to duplicate the entire parameters all the time. Is there anyway to avoid that?

**For ex:**
In my say a Product model:

```
named_scope :example1, lambda{ |parameter1, parameter2|{
 //some code here//
 }
}

named_scope :example2, lambda{ |parameter1, parameter2|{
 //some code here//
 }
}

named_scope :example3, lambda{ |parameter1, parameter2|{
 //some code here//
 }
}
```

Now, I want to use these based on condition

```
if(condition)

Product.example1(param1, param2)

elsif (condition)

Product.example2(param1, param2)

else

Product.example3(param1, param2)
```

**Is there any way to call it like this in ruby:**

```
variable = example1 //I can get the name of named_scope here

Product.variable(param1, param2). //The relevant named_scope should be used.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) do send Product a message (aka call a method).

```
Product.send(variable,param1,param2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @bento... Worked like a charm...Need 15 rep points to vote up this answer :(